# csh script syntax

Tags: shell, csh

I am new to csh script this is the first time i am writing any script:
Here is code:

```
#!/bin/csh

#arg1 path 
#arg2 condition 
#arg3 number of files 
#arg4-argN name of files

set i=0 
while ( $i < $3 ) 
        if ($2 == 0) then 
                cp /remote/$1/$($i+4) $1/new.$( $i+4 ) 
                p4 add $1/new.$($i+4) 
        else 
                p4 edit $1/new.$($i+4) 
                cp /remote/$1/$($i+4) $1/new.$($i+4)
        endif 
        $i = $i+1 
end
```

but here i am kepp on getting error. Illegal variable name.
I have read some tutorial but not getting any thing related.
Please help.
Thx in adv.

Comment: please ignore "/"  before "#" i hv added them as its taking that line as bold

Comment: As you're new to shell scripting, you should become aware that there are [doubts about the wisdom of writing shell scripts in csh](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/). I'm supposing that you have a choice.

Comment: thx ruakh it looks much better now :)

Comment: P.S. I want to admit that c shell doubts are a matter of opinion. Mine for example.

Comment: @miopret  Not just yours!   The syntax of `csh` is inherently ambiguous (even more so that `sh`!), and it has been clinically proven that excessive use of `csh` leads to dementia, psoriasis, and a whole host of other problems.  In all seriousness, everyone "new to csh" needs to be warned early that choosing `csh` is a step in the wrong direction in terms of becoming a better developer.

Comment: Should that be `@ i = $i + 1`? Also, you could calculate the number of files from `${#argv}` instead of depending on the user entering a correct number.

Comment: thx @minopret and william for valuable info.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the flags -v and -x in the first line to see what the script does

```
#!/bin/csh -vx
```

The Problem occurs in the parts where you try to add four to your counter variable

```
$($i+4)
```

csh can't add that way. I'd use a temporary variable to add four to your counter and then use that variable in all the calls

```
@ i = 0 
while ( $i < $3 ) 
        @ iplusfour = $i + 4
        if ($2 == 0) then 
                cp /remote/$1/$($i+4) $1/new.$iplusfour 
                p4 add $1/new.$iplusfour 
        else 
                p4 edit $1/new.$iplusfour 
                cp /remote/$1/$iplusfour $1/new.$iplusfour 
        endif 
        @i = $i + 1 
end
```

I also incorporated Willams's comment.

Answer (score 0):

The last increment can be simplified to `@ i++`, i.e. retouching muluman88's solution:

```
@ i = 0 
while ( $i < $3 ) 
    @ iplusfour = $i + 4
    if ($2 == 0) then 
        cp /remote/$1/$($i+4) $1/new.$iplusfour 
        p4 add $1/new.$iplusfour 
    else 
        p4 edit $1/new.$iplusfour 
        cp /remote/$1/$iplusfour $1/new.$iplusfour 
    endif 
    @ i++
end
```

Make sure that there are  (spaces) after the `@` signs.